# How does Google Domains import your DNS record when you're transferring a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, google, domain-registration, domain-transferring

We are transferring a couple of domains to Google Domains to try it out.

Before finalizing the transfer, there's a `Detect and import my domain's current settings` option.

Google was able to find all our A, MX, CNAME and TXT records.

How is this possible? Is there a mechanism in place to do zone transfers between registrars? I know you can't get the records via normal DNS queries.

Comment: Make a `foo.bar.example.com` record and see if they can find it. I'll bet they're just trying a best-guess situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ceejayoz is right; they just do lookups for common DNS records including Google Apps records which we have.

Found [some documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251236?hl=en#step2) on this:

> Google domains will perform a DNS lookup to look up the resource
>   records associated with the most common subdomains (@, www, blog,
>   etc).